# Question around strong and weak measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was reading this pdf : http://www-f1.ijs.si/~ramsak/seminarji/KnaflicSibka.pdf

and on section 2 they explain the difference between weak and strong measurement.

Am I right if I formulate in a synthetic way the difference like this :

I consider an initial state $|\psi \rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1 \rangle$

I do a measurement protocol.

- With a strong measurement, I will be sure that after my measurement my state collapse either in $|0 \rangle$ or $|1 \rangle$.
- With a weak measurement, I don't project the state in $|0 \rangle$ or
  $|1 \rangle$ but after my measurement I will still have some
  coherences : I would have something like $(\alpha - \epsilon)
     |0\rangle + (\beta + \epsilon) |1 \rangle$

  Like I am "closer" to the $|1 \rangle$ in my example but I don't have
  fully projected on those states.

Is my summarization correct ?

And to be sure : so in the end strong measurement = projective measurement (two words for a same thing) ?

Comment: I think your summary is correct. And I agree that a strong measurement is equivalent to a projective measurement.